# Getting CN entry of an authenticated ldap user

Tags: authentication, spring-security, spring-ldap

I'm doing my first steps on LDAP with spring boot. I have managed to authenticate my user which is listed in my ldif file:

```
dn: dc=parascus,dc=de
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
objectclass: extensibleObject
dc: parascus

dn: ou=groups,dc=parascus,dc=de
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: ou=people,dc=parascus,dc=de
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: uid=jsmith,ou=people,dc=parascus,dc=de
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Smith, John
sn: Smith
uid: jsmith
userPassword: scrambled

dn: cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=parascus,dc=de
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: developers
ou: developer
uniqueMember: uid=jsmith,ou=people,dc=parascus,dc=de
```

Now I'm in my controller method and try to get the cn property "Smith, John":

```
@GetMapping("/profile")
public String index(Authentication authentication) {
    return "Profile of " + authentication.getName();
}
```

But I only get the uid "jsmith". Can somebody give me a hint how I can get all the information or at last the cn entry?

Kind Regards

Parascus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [supply a `UserDetailsContextMapper`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/ldap/src/main/java/example/SecurityConfig.java#L61) to tell Spring Security how to extract details from the `DirContext`.

You do this when [exposing the `LdapAuthenticationProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-ldap-bind):

```java
@Bean
LdapAuthenticationProvider ldap(LdapAuthenticator authenticator) {
    LdapAuthenticationProvider ldap = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(authenticator);
    ldap.setUserDetailsContextMapper(new PersonContextMapper());
    return ldap;
}
```

Spring Security ships with a couple of built-in context mappers, one for the `person` schema (`PersonContextMapper`) and another for the `inetOrgPerson` schema (`InetOrgPersonContextMapper`).

With the above configuration, you can do either:

```java
public String index(Authentication authentication) {
    Person person = (Person) authentication.getPrincipal();
    String[] cn = person.getCn();
    return "Profile of " + cn[cn.length - 1];
}
```

or

```java
public String index(@AuthenticationPrincipal Person person) {
    String[] cn = person.getCn();
    return "Profile of " + cn[cn.length - 1];
}
```

If your entries use neither the `person` nor the `inetOrgPerson` schema, you can create your own `UserDetailsContextMapper`.

Comment: Thank you jzheaux for your quick response.